# How to take reverse of string

Tags: c++, c, string

I have string

```
 string s1="5 2 13 * +" //as prefix expression.
```

I want to obtain reversed of above matrix like this.

`"+ * 13 2 5"`

I have tried stringstream but it make `"+ * 31 2 5"` and I lost my `"13"` and I gets `"31"`. This not good my computation.

How can I do? For helping thanks.

Comment: @juanchopanza "13" will still get reversed, right?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey silly me, I keep thinking the question titles mean something.

Comment: Looks like you do not want to reverse the "string". You have a two dimensional array like [["5"],["2"], ["13"], ["*"], ["+"]] and you want to reverse the outer array. Hope that answers your question too :-)

Comment: You'll probably need `strtok()`

Comment: Note that this is probably not the answer to the question you really wanted to ask, which is how to change postfix to prefix. The correct answer is `+ 5 * 2 13`. Of course, `+` and `*` are commutative so the end result is the same, but there are operators which are not. Try, for example, `5 2 13 / -` which is certainly not the same as the prefix expression `- / 13 2 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to reverse is in str and the delimiters between values are whitespace characters:

```
stringstream ss(str);
string answer, current;
answer.clear();
while (ss >> current) answer = current + " " + answer;
answer.erase(answer.size()-1, 1);     // eliminate space in the end of answer
```

Comment: it return same string. not reversed. ?

Comment: @burakim Sorry, I had a mistake. I edited my answer with new code, which you can try.

Comment: Thank you last edited is correct and very simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
    std::string s = "5 2 13 * +";
    std::forward_list<std::string> lst;
    std::istringstream is( s );

    for ( std::string t; std::getline( is, t, ' ' ); ) lst.push_front( t );
    s.clear();

    for ( std::string t : lst ) s += t + ' ';

    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
```

Or without std::getline

```
    std::string s = "5 2 13 * +";
    std::forward_list<std::string> lst;
    std::istringstream is( s );

    while ( is >> s ) lst.push_front( s );

    s.clear();
    for ( std::string t : lst ) s += t + ' ';

    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
```